# copy content from other website to your based on div

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

```
<html>
        <div class="product-tile ">

                <div class="product-image">

                    <img src="1.jpg">
                    <img src="2.jpg">

                </div>

                <div class="brand">

                        <a href="example1.html" class="brand-link">
                            Example1
                        </a>

                </div>

                <div class="product-name">
                    <a href="/product/example1.html" class="name-link">Craquelé-Effect Leather Square-Toe Mules</a>
                </div>

                </div>

        <div class="product-tile ">

                <div class="product-image">

                    <img src="11.jpg">
                    <img src="12.jpg">

                </div>

                <div class="brand">

                        <a href="example2.html" class="brand-link">
                            Example2
                        </a>

                </div>

                <div class="product-name">
                    <a href="/product/example1.html" class="name-link">Craquelé-Effect </a>
                </div>

            </div>

</html>
```

My content is like this in `HTML` and want to copy it on my website.
My code is like how to get the title, images, brand and there price. I've used `file_get_html` in it but I'm getting issue in fetching the datalike brand and price.

```
require('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html('new_arrival.html');

//$product = []; 

foreach ($html->find('div.wrap-desc') as $pro) {

        $proDetails = $pro->find('div.brand');


}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using jQuery you can get the contents of a DOM element using .html():

```
$('html').html()
```

Alternatively in vanillaJS:

```
let x = document.getElementByTagName('html')
console.log(x.innerHTML)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML

Comment: "If you are using jQuery" — They aren't. They are using PHP's Simple HTML Dom. That is clearly indicated by the tags on the question and the code inside it.

Comment: Thanks Max i am not using just only php and main div is product tile and other are brand price,image inside please also mention foreach for this